# Seam pages.xml file not being used

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, tomcat7, seam2

I'm trying to add breadcrumbs to my site based on this [example](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-user/2006-October/016024.html).

The issue is the action method in the page tag of pages.xml file is never called. I don't know if I have to configure anything in my web.xml. I tried browsing for solution with no good results. Please do help.

I'm using JSF 2, Seam 2.2.2, Tomcat 7 with Eclipse IDE. And all my web files are of .jsp extension. Here is my web.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>Max3dsJSF</display-name>
      <filter> 
          <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name> 
          <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name> 
          <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 
          <init-param> 
           <param-name>forceparser</param-name> 
           <param-value>false</param-value> 
          </init-param> 
        </filter> 
        <filter-mapping> 
          <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name> 
          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
          <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
          <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
          <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
        </filter-mapping>
        <filter>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.web.SeamFilter</filter-class>
        </filter> 
        <filter-mapping> 
          <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
        <context-param> 
      <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name> 
      <param-value>false</param-value> 
    </context-param> 

      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/Index.jsp </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class> 
 </listener> 

</web-app>
```

Faces_config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"    
version="1.2">   
<application>

<locale-config>
    <default-locale>nl_NL</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    </application>
Managed beans and navigation rukes......
</faces-config>
```

Thanks in advance!

Jane

Comment: You said that you're using JSF 2, but your `faces-config.xml` causes it to run in JSF 1.2 fallback modus and hence you lose all JSF 2 advantages!

Comment: I didn't even realize it till you pointed out. :( But then I changed it to JSF 2.0 and the Breadcrumb still didn't work.

Comment: It's a different problem. I didn't post it as an answer, but just as a comment :)